# Prove that $f(x)$ is non-increasing on $(0,1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

Let $f(x)$ be continuous in the interval $I=(0,1)$. Define $D_+f(x_0)=\liminf_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}$. Put $S=\{x\in I:D_+f(x)<0\}$. Suppose that the set $f(I\setminus S)$ does not contain any non-empty open interval. Prove that $f(x)$ is non-increasing.

My attempt: Suppose that $f(x)$ is increasing on $(a,b) \subset (0,1)$, and $a <b$.

This implies $f^{'}(x)>0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$. i.e $D_{+}f(x)>0$ for all $x \in (a,b)$.

Now, $S=(a,b)^c$, and $I \setminus S=I \cap S^c=(a,b)$.

Since, $I\setminus S$ is connected and $f$ is a continuous function. This implies $f(I\setminus S)$ is a connected set. This is a contradiction. Hence $f(x)$ is non increasing on $I$.

Is this attempt correct?

Comment: The contrapositive of “non-increasing” is that $f(a) < f(b)$ for *some* $a < b$, not that $f$ is increasing. Also you cannot assume that $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: Btw: I noticed that you got answers for many of your questions, but never *accepted* an answer so far. If you are not aware of it: Accepting an answer is important as it both rewards posters for solving your problem and informs others that your issue is resolved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/196432) for more information.

Comment: Yes . Thanks. I understand. I cannot choose differentiability here because function is continuous given not differentiability.